# How can I merge two files with numbers into a new file and make it sorted?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

How can I merge two files with numbers into a new file and make it sorted?

Code:

```
#combining the two files
filenames = ["numbers1.txt", "numbers2.txt"]
    with open("allNumbers.txt", "w") as al_no:
       **#iterating through the filenames list**
        for f in filenames:
           with open(f) as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    al_no.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can use.

The first approach is to loop through, append the lines to a list, sort the list and then write that out to the file.

```
filenames = ["numbers1.txt", "numbers2.txt"]

# Step 1: merge the lines into a list
lines = []
for f in filenames:
   with open(f) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            lines.append(line)

# Step 2: write the list out to the file in a sorted order
with open("allNumbers.txt", "w") as all_no:
    all_no.write(''.join(sorted(lines, key=lambda x: int(x.strip()))))
```

It is more succinct (and Pythonic) to use list comprehensions instead:

```
filenames = ["numbers1.txt", "numbers2.txt"]

lines = [line for sublist in [open(f).readlines() for f in filenames] for line in sublist]
with open("allNumbers.txt", "w") as all_no:
    all_no.write(''.join(sorted(lines, key=lambda x: int(x.strip()))))
```

Remember that when sorting, you need to use the `key` argument to `sorted` to ensure a numeric sort is done, rather than the default lexicographic sort.

This code assumes that each line in the source files contains a number, which is likely given the current approach you've taken.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a detailed description or file, I worked on it with a prediction.

try this code:

```
# Reading data from file1
with open('numbers1.txt') as fp:
    data = fp.read()

# Reading data from file2
with open('numbers2.txt') as fp:
    data2 = fp.read()

# Merging 2 files
data += "\n"
data += data2

# Covert str to list
list_data = data.split()

# Covert list(item) to int
list_data = list(map(int, list_data))

# Sort list(item)
list_data.sort()

# save file
with open('allNumbers.txt', 'w') as file:
    for data in list_data:
        file.write("%s\n" % data)
```

You can change the structure and use it.

good luck!